# Unsetting Header Row in python-docx or setting first column as title column

Tags: python, ms-word, openxml, python-docx

I am generating multiple tables with the python-docx but I have issue that some tables are rotated == having headers in the first column instead of the first row.

Is there any possibility how to uncheck following option with the python-docx or with accessing xml directly?

[image: Microsoft Word settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did found workaround how to achieve what I needed. It is possible to directly access each paragraph in each cell and set it manually to bold during creation.

This example makes first column bold and leaving rest of the table normal:

```py
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=len(data))
table.style = 'Table Grid'
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
# Some fake data
row_cells[0].text = data[0]
row_cells[1].text = data[1]
row_cells[2].text = data[2]
# ...
# This gets Heading Row 1 paragraph and sets it to bold
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
```

Answer (score 1):

These options specifie whether the corresponding part of a ***Table Style*** definition applied to a table.

In the Word Open XML, these are listed as attributes of the `w:tblLook` element. The heading row is the attribute `w:firstRow`. It's an on/off | true/false setting so to turn it off the attribute needs to be set to `0` (false).

I can't tell you whether python-docx supports this (the Open XML SDK does). But this information will let you change it in the XML directly and possibly search the language reference for python-docx.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out if I won't be able to do it directly through python-docx

Comment: You had great idea but I've spent a few hours trying to implement that with OXML but had no luck making it work. I decided to step back, look at issue again and found simple workaround by using simple unformmated style and manually bolding cells I need.